# Armijo rule intuition and implementation

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I am minimizing a convex function $f(x,y)$ using the steepest descent method:
$$\mathbf{x}_{n+1}=\mathbf{x}_n-\gamma \nabla F(\mathbf{x}_n),\ n \ge 0$$

My function is defined over a specific domain $D = \{(x, y) \in R^2 : 2x^2+y^2 < 10\}$, if my $x_{n+1}$ goes out of bound, my method diverge. I was told to choose $\gamma$ using armijo rule to stay inbound.

Can someone explain to me the method and also describe a pseudo code for implementing it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfe_conditions#Armijo_rule_and_curvature

Comment: @Rahul: I saw this before writing the question. I didn't get from there.

Comment: I think it will help to write down your objective function, so people see that it approaches infinity near the boundary of the constraint set.

Comment: Exactly. If the domain is a natural consequence of the function---that is, if the function approaches $+\infty$ at the boundary---then there is no need for the projection step in @Rahul's answer. The backtracking alone will take care of matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pseudo Code for Steepest Descent using Armijo's Rule:**

> Given $x_k$, $maxiter$, other conditions
>
> Compute $\nabla F(x_k)$
>
> $objold \leftarrow 0$
>
> Define $\sigma \ \& \beta$ [between $(0,1)$]
>
> while $(iter < maxiter)$ && (other conditions)
>
> > $flag \leftarrow 0$
> >
> > $s_k \leftarrow 1$
> >
> > while $flag \neq 1$
> >
> > > $x_{new} = x_k-s_k \nabla F(x_k)$
> > >
> > > if $x_{proj} \notin D$
> > >
> > > > $x_{proj}=P_D (x_{new})$ [Projection operation - here it will be the point where the line joining the $x_{new}$ and $(0,0)$ cuts the ellipse.]
> > >
> > > end
> > >
> > > $objnew = F(x_{proj})$
> > >
> > > if $(objnew-objold) \leq \sigma*\nabla F(x_k)'*(x_{proj}-x_k)$
> > >
> > > > $flag \leftarrow 1$
> > >
> > > else
> > >
> > > > $s_k \leftarrow s_k\times\beta$
> > >
> > > end
> >
> > end
>
> $x_k \leftarrow x_{proj}$
>
> Compute $\nabla F(x_k)$
>
> $objold \leftarrow objnew$
>
> end

(Point to be noted: there are various ways to implement it.)

Comment: what is the projection operation?

Comment: You have project the $x_{new}$ into your constraint set. To get a unique projection, your constraint set must be closed and convex. In this case, which you have.

Comment: But the constraint set isn't closed.

Comment: Oho. I did not noticed that. Then I think, the problem may not be solved because $\min$ may not exist. Instead you have to look for the $\inf$ for which the projection operation will not be a problem.

Comment: There isn't a constraint set here, though; there is a domain. @littleO is right above: the proper thing to do depends on the precise function.

Comment: Perfect .. this implementation work

Comment: @MichaelGrant, Sir, though I have commented on his previous post, but I did not follow it after that. I am completely agree with you that for such an objective function, we do not need to apply any kind of optimization technique. We can directly compute the answer and it is indeed $(0,0)$.